# how to cover the json string from test class?

Tags: apex, unit-test, json, code-coverage

```
public static String httpJsonResponseString;
 HTTPResponse res_usage;
    if(!Test.isRunningTest()){
        res_usage = http_usage.send(req);
    }else{
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.setBody(httpJsonResponseString);
        res.setStatusCode(200);
        res_usage = res;
    }
```

in this i am using condition is res.setbody(variable) this is running from test class, now how i satisfy this from test class??
i just want that json string is pass in this and get the value, how i can satisfy that because when i tried to do it with simple inserting the account then it is getting null pointer exception.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

[Test a Callout with HttpCalloutMock](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_integration_services/units/apex_integration_rest_callouts) trailhead module is quite good in explaining on how to write proper test.

Also refer [Testing HTTP Callouts by Implementing the HttpCalloutMock Interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm).

Comment: But this is not a Mock callout..actually in this we are passing a hardcoded id in json string 'account_name":"20&#124;20 Research","sf_account_id":"001d000001nBAwtAAG" like this, so just save from harcoded string we are using variable, so when i pass the value in this from test class then it get the value in this variable.

Comment: and this is i don't know how to pass the value in variable from test class?

Comment: With [`HttpCalloutMock`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm), you don't need to skip the callout with  `Test.isRunningTest()`. Its testing mock test in right way.

Comment: yes may be you are right but this is not written by me, it is written by someone other and i need to create only test class of this, so i can't do any changes in main code...so can you please tell me the solution for this which i have posted?

Comment: Have you had a look at the documentation attached? it clearly explains on how to write a test class for HTTP request callout. I didn't wanted to quote the whole documentation in the answer. Have already pointed you in right direction, I think.

Comment: sorry @rahul but i didn't know how to use that because i guess that is not satisfying my condition..i am new in web services and get the chance to make test class of this...can you please help me in this in more detail, so i pass this..if you want then i can give more information on this. Please help me.

Comment: Thank you for all your support. The thing that i was asking have simple ans like class.httpJsonResponseString = json string and problem solved . there is no need of mock calls.